# Create OHLC Bars From Dictionaries - Websocket Stream

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pivot, reshape

I am connecting to a websocket that sends messages in this format:

```
msg = {'ev': 'A', 'sym': 'SPY', 'v': 222, 'av': 107783639, 'op': 391.841, 'vw': 396.45, 'o': 396.45, 'c': 396.45, 'h': 396.45, 'l': 396.45, 'a': 393.1093, 'z': 27, 's': 1679696390000, 'e': 1679696391000}
```

I have tried converting each msg to a dataframe and setting the columns using the code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(msg.items()))
df = df.T
df.columns = df.iloc[1]
df = df.T
```

I want to be able to add each new message to the end of the df until I have a df of 60 rows. Then I planned on using pd.resample() possibly to convert it into 1 hour bars so that I can then append it to the bulk data I've got downloaded.

How can I at least get to the point where it's appending the rows, and preferably in the most efficient way possible. I'm guessing what I've tried so far could be done with less code.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by maintaining a list of dictionaries and converting it into a DataFrame after collecting 60 messages.

Here is an example, notice that you gonna have to adapt my example to the `msgs` list as they arrive:

```
import pandas as pd

msgs = []

for _ in range(60):
    msg = {'ev': 'A', 'sym': 'SPY', 'v': 222, 'av': 107783639, 'op': 391.841, 'vw': 396.45, 'o': 396.45, 'c': 396.45, 'h': 396.45, 'l': 396.45, 'a': 393.1093, 'z': 27, 's': 1679696390000, 'e': 1679696391000}
    msgs.append(msg)

df = pd.DataFrame(msgs)

df['s'] = pd.to_datetime(df['s'], unit='ms')
df['e'] = pd.to_datetime(df['e'], unit='ms')

df.set_index('s', inplace=True)


ohlc = df.resample('1H').agg({'o': 'first', 'h': 'max', 'l': 'min', 'c': 'last'})

print(ohlc)
```

Comment: That seems easy enough, thanks! Gotta wait till market opens at 4am EST on Monday to test it but looks like it should do the trick.